# Cannot solve $ y = xy'+x^3(y')^2 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following differential equation:
$$ y = xy'+x^3(y')^2 $$

I have tried almost every method for solving first order differential equations, and did many substitutions $ y=u(x)p(x) $, using various functions as $ u(x) $. However, I still cannot find its general solution.

I would appreciate any hint.

Comment: What makes you think there's an elementary solution?

Comment: It is taken from a book's chapter where every ODE has an elementary solution. This is the only one left, so I presume it has one too.

Comment: I've seen differential equations that arise, say, in a differential geometric context, where it helps to notice that $xy'-y = x^2(y/x)'$, but this particular equation seems horrible.

Comment: *I would appreciate any hint.* - Notice that by dividing both sides by *x*, the expression on the right becomes symmetrical.

Comment: Guessing a solution of the form $y(x) = c\, x^{\alpha}$, substituting it in, and solving for $c$ and $\alpha$ yields $y(x) = 2/x$ as one solution.

Comment: @GeorgeG. can you share the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation has four solutions all roughly as awful as this one (produced by Mathematica 11.3):
$$  y(x) = -\frac{\sqrt{3} x \sqrt{-\frac{c_1^2 x^3-\sqrt[3]{-c_1^6 x^9+2160
   c_1^8 x^7+93312 c_1^{10} x^5+48 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{c_1^{14} \left(-x^{10}\right)
   \left(x^2-108 c_1^2\right){}^3}}-\frac{c_1^4 x^6}{\sqrt[3]{-c_1^6 x^9+2160
   c_1^8 x^7+93312 c_1^{10} x^5+48 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{c_1^{14} \left(-x^{10}\right)
   \left(x^2-108 c_1^2\right){}^3}}}-\frac{864 c_1^6 x^4}{\sqrt[3]{-c_1^6 x^9+2160
   c_1^8 x^7+93312 c_1^{10} x^5+48 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{c_1^{14} \left(-x^{10}\right)
   \left(x^2-108 c_1^2\right){}^3}}}-48 c_1^4 x}{c_1^4 x^3}}+\sqrt{3} x
   \sqrt{-\frac{x \left(864 c_1^2+x^2\right)}{\sqrt[3]{-c_1^6 x^9+2160 c_1^8
   x^7+93312 c_1^{10} x^5+48 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{c_1^{14} \left(-x^{10}\right)
   \left(x^2-108 c_1^2\right){}^3}}}-\frac{\sqrt[3]{-c_1^6 x^9+2160 c_1^8
   x^7+93312 c_1^{10} x^5+48 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{c_1^{14} \left(-x^{10}\right)
   \left(x^2-108 c_1^2\right){}^3}}}{c_1^4 x^3}+\frac{96 \sqrt{3} \left(4
   c_1^2+x^2\right)}{c_1^2 x^3 \sqrt{-\frac{c_1^2 x^3-\sqrt[3]{-c_1^6 x^9+2160
   c_1^8 x^7+93312 c_1^{10} x^5+48 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{c_1^{14} \left(-x^{10}\right)
   \left(x^2-108 c_1^2\right){}^3}}-\frac{c_1^4 x^6}{\sqrt[3]{-c_1^6 x^9+2160
   c_1^8 x^7+93312 c_1^{10} x^5+48 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{c_1^{14} \left(-x^{10}\right)
   \left(x^2-108 c_1^2\right){}^3}}}-\frac{864 c_1^6 x^4}{\sqrt[3]{-c_1^6 x^9+2160
   c_1^8 x^7+93312 c_1^{10} x^5+48 \sqrt{3} \sqrt{c_1^{14} \left(-x^{10}\right)
   \left(x^2-108 c_1^2\right){}^3}}}-48 c_1^4 x}{c_1^4
   x^3}}}-\frac{2}{c_1^2}+\frac{96}{x^2}}-36}{24 x}  
\text{,}$$
where $c_1$ is the constant of integration.

(It is likely that this cannot be rendered intelligibly by the MathJax interperter.  However, the point is that this solution has no hope of being elementary, which seems to be adequately indicated.)

Comment: **Hint:** Have you tried expressing *x* as a function of *y* ? Or rephrasing the expression in terms of $z = y/x$ ?

Comment: @Lucian: Sounds more like an Answer to the Question...

Answer (score 1):

Writing the equation as 
$$
y=px+x^3p^2\tag1
$$
with $p=y'(x)$ and thus by the chain rule $\dot y(p)=p\dot x(p)$ gives under derivation by $p$
$$
p\dot x=\dot y=x+p\dot x+2x^3p+3x^2p^2\dot x\implies 1+2x^2p+3xp^2\dot x
\tag2$$
Use $u=\frac12x^2$, then 
$$
0=1+4pu+3p^2\dot u
\tag3$$
is linear in $u$ with integrating factor $p^{4/3-2}=p^{-2/3}$
$$
C=\frac13p^{1/3}+3p^{4/3}u\implies u=Cp^{-4/3}-\frac{p^{-1}}3
\tag4$$
Resolving backwards, one can find an expression for $x(p)$ and inserting into the first equation (1) also an expression for $y(p)$. These are still relatively simple. Elimination of $p$ (or $p^{1/3})$ will not be easy or result in nice expressions, as the equation (4) is a 4th degree polynomial equation for $p^{1/3}$.

Comment: You are correct. There was a mistake in one of the intermediate steps. Thanks a lot for pointing out.